# Ubermenu widget area not updating

Tags: wordpress, widget

I have been up for hours trying to figure this out and its driving me mad!

I have a menu with an *ubermenu* widget area. The widget area is updating the content in the database `wp-options` and showing the updated content in the back end but its not displaying changes in the front end.

Comment: Sounds like a template issue. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "Updated in the back end"? Have you defined actual widget areas for front-end display?

Comment: Yes if I update the widget in the back end its updating and the changes are also updated in the database but in ubermenu they remain unchanged.

Comment: WHAT widget you are using ?

Comment: Im not missing any widgets, I got it down to a caching problem.